# Display PNG image with transparent background color using Gdiplus

Tags: gdi+

I have png in Gdiplus::image. I can render image using below code.

```
Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc);
graphics.DrawImage(m_pBitmap, 0, 0);
```

Now how to  draw png with a transparent color so all pixels of a certain color (for example:  `RGB(255,255,255)`) show transparently and you can see the background where the transparent pixels are using Gdiplus.

Can I get any sample code?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ImageAttributes` and `SetColorKey`

```
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bm(L"transparent.png", TRUE);
    if(bm.GetLastStatus() == Gdiplus::Status::Ok)
    {
        Gdiplus::Graphics gr(hdc);

        Gdiplus::ImageAttributes attr;
        attr.SetColorKey(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 255), Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 255),
            Gdiplus::ColorAdjustTypeBitmap);

        gr.DrawImage(
            &bm,
            Gdiplus::Rect(0, 0, bm.GetWidth(), bm.GetHeight()),
            0, 0, bm.GetWidth(), bm.GetHeight(),
            Gdiplus::UnitPixel,
            &attr);
    }
    else
        MessageBox(0, L"error", 0, 0);
```